# If field is null, pull certain fields; otherwise, pull other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the following table:

```
TestTable  
  ColumnA  
  Column1  
  Column2  
  Column3  
  Column4
```

I want to write a simple SQL statement that checks ColumnA and depending on whether it is null or not returns certain columns.

Something like (pseudo):

```
If ColumnA Is Null
  SELECT ColumnA, Column1, Column2 
  FROM TestTable
Else
  SELECT ColumnA, Column3, Column4
  FROM TestTable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using? You have both Oracle and SQL Server tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use SQL CASE expressions:

```
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NULL THEN Column1 ELSE Column3 END AS ColumnB,
    CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NULL THEN Column2 ELSE Column4 END AS ColumnC
FROM
    TestTable
```

See:
[CASE (SQL-Server Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)
[CASE Expressions (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a couple of routes, none are necessarily pretty...

People often find the first one, then look for something better.  I'm not sure that there really is anything better.

```
SELECT
  ColumnA,
  CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NULL THEN Column1 ELSE Column2 END AS ColumnB,
  CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NULL THEN Column3 ELSE Column4 END AS ColumnC
FROM
  yourTable
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  yourTable.ColumnA,
  subTable.ColumnB,
  subTable.ColumnC
FROM
  yourTable
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT yourTable.Column1 AS ColumnB, yourTable.Column3 AS ColumnC WHERE yourTable.ColumnA IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yourTable.Column2 AS ColumnB, yourTable.Column4 AS ColumnC WHERE yourTable.ColumnA IS NOT NULL
)
  AS subTable
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  ColumnA,
  Column1 AS ColumnB,
  Column2 AS ColumnC
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  ColumnA IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
  ColumnA,
  Column2 AS ColumnB,
  Column4 AS ColumnC
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  ColumnA IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

One more way to skin this particular cat:

```
SELECT ColumnA,
       NVL2(ColumnA, Column3, Column1),
       NVL2(ColumnA, Column4, Column2)
  FROM TestTable
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Note: `NVL2()` takes string parameters, which means an implicit cast, and then possibly back to the native data-type depending on need.

Comment: @Dems `NVL2` works with "any data types except LONG": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions120.htm#i91806  (Although if Column[A|1|2|3|4] are different types then there could certainly be problems, but that's true of any of the answers here.)

Comment: @Dems : per the docs for NVL2 at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286.pdf it seems that if the second argument is numeric the database will determine which argument has the highest numeric precedence and will return a value of that type.  There's also a note that it will accept parameters of any type, except that LONG is forbidden for the second and third arguments.  At least this appears to be so under 11.1.  YMMV.